# Sanity Slug works in localhost but not on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, slug, sanity

So I am building a react and sanity blog website. When I run the app on localhost, my blog post slugs work, copying the slugs and opening in a new tab works but when I deployed it on Netlify, I get a 404 page, what going on?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me

In your public folder, create a "_redirects" - without the quotes, file and add the following lines of code

```
/*  /index.html  200
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check you astro.config.mjs, and if there is an output key, it should be "static", check if is "server" instead, this works for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).